# How do I use Wordpress' delete() function to delete a row in a table upon clicking a link?

Tags: php, html, sql, database, wordpress

I have a form that adds data to my Wordpress database, and is then displayed on the same page. Within the table I have added a column called "Action" where there is, for each row, a link called "Delete" .

I would like to use this link to delete any given row.

The code I am working with looks like this.

```
$id = "#";
$table = 'cogs';
$wpdb->delete( $table, array( 'id' => $id ) );
```

The "#" in the $id variable is just a placeholder.

Is there a way to connect the "delete" link to the $id variable? Or do I need to use different code all-together?

This is the PHP for the table. I am not sure what I should put in for the URL link with in the  tag. I tried linking it back to the page, but it still does not remove the row.

```
            foreach($cogs as $cogs){

                echo "<tr>";

                    echo "<td>".$cogs->id."</td>";

                    echo "<td>".$cogs->date."</td>";

                    echo "<td>".$cogs->source."</td>";

                    echo "<td>".$cogs->items_purchased."</td>";

                    echo "<td>".$cogs->receipt_total."</td>";
                    
                    echo "<td>"<a href="URL?id= <?php echo $id; ?>">Delete</a>"</td>"
                            
                            if(isset($_GET['id']) &&!empty($_GET['id'])){
                            
                                $id = $_GET['id'];
                                $table = 'cogs';
                                $wpdb->delete( $table, array( 'id' => $id ) );  
                                wp_redirect('/cost-of-goods-sold');
                                exit();
                    
                            } 
                         
                echo "</tr>";

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your loop where you are showing delete action button, pass dynamic id ($id) in this case

`<a href="URL?id=<?phpecho $id; ?>">Delete</a>`

and the code will be

```
<?php
  if(isset($_GET['id']) &&!empty($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $table = 'cogs';
    $wpdb->delete( $table, array( 'id' => $id ) );  
    wp_redirect('URL');
}
?>
```

Comment: I updated the original post with the code you provided. I am not sure what URL link I should be using within the <a> tag. Also, does the PHP code look right?